# Why are the properties of a deleted tableView section cached?

Tags: swift, uitableview

In a tableView, before data is downloaded from a database, I display a placeholder cell with some static content and I change the properties of that cell, hide several buttons and disable user interaction.
What I just found out is that, even though I delete the section of the cell at indexPath.section 0, when new data arrives and I insert it at the same index, the old settings for the dequeued cell are cached.  I had previously thought that once I call `self.tableView.deleteSections(indexVal, with: .automatic)`, the cell would be deleted and a new cell would be dequeued. Could anyone explain me this behaviour?
I know this is a trivial question, but I spent several hours to find this bug in a pile of code.

```
     var media = [Media]()

       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.mediaCell, for: indexPath) as! MediaTableViewCell
     cell.delegate = self

  if firstMessagesLoaded == false {

         //hide some buttons and disable userInteraction
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return cell
    }

  if firstMessagesLoaded == true {
    //it turns out I have to enable userInteraction again here, otherwise it will remain disabled even though the section at this indexPath was deleted previously
    // cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
      return cell
    }
   }


 func fetchMediaChildAdded() {
    let newMedia = Media() //received from database ...

      //when new media is fetched, remove the placeholder media from array, delete the section and add new data
     if self.firstMessagesLoaded == false {
           self.firstMessagesLoaded = true

            //remove the mediaPlaceholder and delete it's section
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.media.remove(at: 0)
            let indexVal = IndexSet(integer: 0)
            self.tableView.deleteSections(indexVal, with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
           if !self.media.contains(newMedia) {
            self.media.insert(newMedia, at: 0)
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug. It's a feature.

Cells are reused (for performance reasons). That's the default behavior which the name `dequeueReusableCell` implies.

- When a cell disappears from screen it is moved to a pool as it is.
- When `dequeueReusableCell` is called a cell is taken out of the pool. You - the developer – are responsible for setting all UI elements to a defined state.

Side note:

The second condition `firstMessagesLoaded == false` will never be reached and `beginUpdates / endUpdates` has no effect at all for a single insert/delete operation.